# Running WebServerSecure and PubSubClient on ESP8266

Tags: webserver, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I wrote a sketch for ESP8266. This sketch reads some sensor data and published it via MQTT. In addition I want to let a Web server provide the same data as HTML, or JSON web service.

The MQTT publish is triggered via a TaskScheduler timer.

Both functions, MQTT and Web server, work for itself, but sadly not together. Here's a simplified sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServerSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <TaskScheduler.h>

#include <My_WLAN.h>                          // provices connection to local WLAN and network settings

const char DNS_NAME[] = "myserver.local";
const int  HTTPS_PORT = 443;                  // HTTPS
const char MQTT_SVR[] = "myserver.local";
const unsigned int MQTT_PORT = 8883;          // MQTTS

WiFiClientSecure  wifiClient;
PubSubClient      mqttClient(wifiClient);     // MQTT client instance
ESP8266WebServerSecure  server(HTTPS_PORT);   // web server instance

void t1Callback(void);                        // callback method prototypes
Task              t1(60000, TASK_FOREVER, &t1Callback);   // main loop task
Scheduler         timer;                      // task scheduler

static const uint8_t SVR_FINGERPRINT[20] PROGMEM = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x20 };

static const char deviceCert[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[... certificate ...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

static const char deviceKey[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[... key ...]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
)EOF";


/* *****************************
      MQTT_connect
 * *****************************/
void MQTT_connect()
{
  int attempt = 0;
  /* loop until reconnected */
  while (!mqttClient.connected() && attempt < 10) {
    attempt++;
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection ("); Serial.print(attempt); Serial.print(")...");

    mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_SVR, MQTT_PORT);

    if (mqttClient.connect(DNS_NAME)) {
      Serial.println("success");

    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, status code = "); Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(". - Try again in 5 seconds...");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}


/* *****************************
      Web Server handleRoot
 * *****************************/
void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // on

  Serial.println("WebServer ROOT");
  server.send(200, "text/html", "WebServer ROOT");

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // off
}

/* *****************************
      Web Server handleNotFound
 * *****************************/
void handleNotFound() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // on

  String message = "File not found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }

  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // off
}


/* *************************
      MQTT_publish_something
 * *************************/
void MQTT_publish_something() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); // on

  char payload[30] = "some_payload_data";

  if (!mqttClient.publish("MQTT/Test", payload, true)) {  // retain message
    Serial.println("MQTT message lost!");
  }

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // off
}


/* *************************
   t1: main timer (callback)
 * *************************/
void t1Callback() {
  my.WiFi_connect();    // check and re-connect to WLAN (in My_WLAN.h)

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    MQTT_connect();

    MQTT_publish_something();
  }
}


/* *************************
      setup
 * *************************/
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);     // internal LED
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // off

  /* -----------------------
        open Serial        |
     ----------------------- */
  Serial.begin(74880);
  while (!Serial);   // wait for Serial being ready

  /* -----------------------
        connect to WLAN    |
     ----------------------- */
  my.WiFi_connect();  // this is connecting to WLAN & error handling (in My_WLAN.h)
  wifiClient.setFingerprint(SVR_FINGERPRINT);

  /* -----------------------
        set mDNS           |
     ----------------------- */
  if (MDNS.begin(DNS_NAME)) {
    Serial.printf("mDNS responder started for %s\n", DNS_NAME);
    MDNS.addService("https", "tcp", HTTPS_PORT);   // add service to MDNS-SD
    MDNS.addService("mqtt",  "tcp", MQTT_PORT);
  } else
    Serial.println("Error setting up mDNS responder!");

  /* -----------------------
        start HTTPS server |
     ----------------------- */
  server.getServer().setRSACert(new X509List(deviceCert), new PrivateKey(deviceKey));

  server.on("/", handleRoot);                 // standard HTML root
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("HTTPS server started.");
  Serial.println();


  /* -----------------------
        start timer        |
     ----------------------- */
  timer.init();
  timer.addTask(t1);
  // line 177:
  timer.enableAll();
}

void loop() {
  MDNS.update();

  // line 184:
  server.handleClient();

  mqttClient.loop();

  timer.execute();
}
```

Running MQTT only works fine and publishes data (I use the mosquitto broker).
Running the Web server (https://...) works fine as well, if commenting out line 177 (so MQTT does not get triggered).

With both functions active, as soon as the first MQTT message had been sent, the web server does not answer any more. I get PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR in FF and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED in Chrome.

I guess, that these libraries somehow mess with each other, or that something confuses with the certificates. However, the fingerprint belongs to the server running mosquitto, while the X509 certificate belongs to the web server running on the ESP8266. These are two different machines and have nothing to do with each other.

Any idea welcome.

Comment: Not a direct response to your question, but why not have the Web Server someplace else?  IOT Rule #1:  Let Sensors Sense,  Let Something Else Report.  I have a number of sensors publishing their readings, but I put my webserver on my Docker server.  I have another Docker container collecting up the Data, and then make it available as a API. An HTML page then reads in the data via JQuery: https://github.com/john2exonets/MqttAPIServer

Comment: Thanks, JD Allen, had that idea as well and this would be a valid alternate solution. But shouldn't it be possible to run both on one machine, or if not why not?

Comment: Sure, you can run both on one machine....but the first time to have to go drag that sensor  back from where it was, just to burn in some new code to add a space on a webpage, you quickly realize the reasons to keep sensors sensing, and not do anything extra ;)  After about four times I had to climb up and retrieve a sensor/web server node, I decided to make my life easy and split the web server part out to a Docker container, where I could make all the changes I liked while sitting at my desk ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect both libraries use port 443, and you can only have one listener on a given port. I've tried creating a BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure object with alternate ports, such as 80 and 8443 but can't get them to work. Worse, there doesn't seem to be a way to stop a listener once a BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure object has started, so it can't be released for later reuse.

I ended up using HTTP to get WiFi credentials, then HTTPS from there on out. Not a very satisfactory solution but it works.

Update: I was able to run a provisioning server on port 443, stop it by calling

```
  BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure provisioningServer(443);
  BearSSL::ESP8266WebServerSecure server(443);

  provisioningServer.close();
  provisioningServer.~ESP8266WebServerSecure(); // note: cannot use TLS on both servers without this line
```

After calling the provisioning server's destructor I was able to start my server on port 443.

Comment: I just wanna point out that the `ESP8266WebServer` base/template class actually has a `stop()` function you can call, but it seems like it didn't quite work at first as you still couldn't reuse the port. This should be fixed as of 9 January 2021: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7818. Also, a client contacting a server on port 443 shouldn't even interfere with a server listening on that port on the same device, as the *local* port used by the client is *not* 443. The code posted by OP only runs one server, so I'd guess the MQTT client ends up somehow blocking the web server.